# Reset width div-element in mobile first stylesheet

Tags: css

I am trying to style the Grid Columns plugin from Justin Tadlock for mobile. Source: https://github.com/justintadlock/grid-columns

In my css file I would like to set the `.column-grid .column width` for mobile to full, and reset the width for `min-width: 768px`

```
.column-grid .column {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 0;

    }

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.column-grid .column {

    }
}
```

I tried `width: 100%` versus `width: auto`, and `display: block` versus `display: inline`. However, it didn't do the trick.

Note, the actual column widths are set within the `.column-grid .column` wrapper.

Any suggestions on how to do this smartly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to stack the columns vertically on mobile devices and have them display as columns on desktop then change the media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.column-grid .column {
 width: 100%;
 }
}
```

Otherwise I'll need to see your markup in context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Tom. Actually, `.column-grid .column` is the (or a) wrapper for the columns. The column widths are set within: [link](https://github.com/justintadlock/grid-columns/blob/master/css/columns.css)

Comment: Could you possibly put a stripped out version of your code into jFiddle? I don't want to make any more assumptions and seeing the code in context will really help.

Answer (score 0):

I just imported the plugins CSS into my stylesheet, at

`@media (min-width: 48em) {` (768px).

I then deregistered the stylesheet the plugin enqueues, as there is no need to serve the same content twice:

```
function remove_grid_columns() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'grid-columns' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'remove_grid_columns' );
```

(1 less HTTP request, yay!) I think this is the best way, the only thing is remembering to update my stylesheet if grid columns updates. But as I'm using SASS if the plugin gets updated I'll just chuck the updated columns.css into my grid_columns.scss file.